# mongodb create index on array field with $ mark is not possible?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing

I want to create an index on array field that have embedded documents.
for instance,

```
foo={ x: { array[ {id:123, y:"h"}, {id:234, y:"z"} ] } }

db.foo.find( { "x.array.1.id": 234 }, {"x.array.$":1} )
```

Works for me.

And I need to create an index for all `x.array.$.id` field values.
so I tried it but failed such as:

```
db.foo.createIndex( { "x.array.$.id" :1 } )
```

> "errmsg" : "Index key contains an illegal field name: field name starts with '$'."

is there any other way to create index for all element value?
thanks in advance.